# Why PDF content missing sometime and sometime it comes fine on Odoo sh in Odoo 14

Tags: pdf, odoo, odoo-12, qweb, odoo.sh

I am getting data by `t-raw` tag from `html field` in `qweb-pdf` report. Its working fine on local but its missing content sometime and sometime works fine on production system. Our production is on `Odoo sh`

For example my Text field is looking like:
[image: Text field is looks like]

When it missing content it looks like:
[image]

And it looks like below when ok
[image]

Need experts opinion on it, how can i fix this issue
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

it was due to *Italic* style. `t-raw` was not getting italic style some time.